# Find file names based on multiple occurrences of a character

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to figure out why my grep command does not work, which should pick those file names within a folder, that have more than 2 `_`in their name:

```
test_file_1.tsv
test_file_2.tsv
test_fi_le_3.tsv
```

I'm running in that folder

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -E "_{3,}"
```

but it returns nothing instead of

```
test_fi_le_3.tsv
```

?

Comment: `"_{3,}"` means 3 or more consecutive underscores

Comment: you need something like `"_*_"` but set the occurence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that `"_{3,}"` matches 3 or more consecutive underscores.

However, you don't even need a `grep` here and use glob pattern in `-name` option of `find` as this one:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*_*_*'
```

```
./test_file_1.tsv
./test_file_2.tsv
./test_fi_le_3.tsv
```

Comment: that is a perfect answer if you know how many occurrences there might be (in my case 3 - 5 I guess), so it is working for me. But what would you do, if you only knew it could occur more than 2 times, maybe 50?

Comment: Actually `-name '*_*_*'` matches it more than 2 times, even 50 occurrences

Comment: Ah yes I see...my first thought was, that I have to set the exact number of occurrences but of course, that was wrong. Thanks!